# Why does mathematica include a condition in the result of this integral?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 - 100*Sin[2*t]^2], {t, 0, u}]
(* ConditionalExpression[1/2 EllipticE[2 u, 100], 
    Cos[4 u] >= 49/50] *)
```

but the answer is just `1/2 EllipticE[2 u, 100]`

`Cos[4 u] >= 49/50` is redundant.

Comment: What version are you using? On MMA 12.0 Win10-64 I also get conditions requesting that `u` be real etc. Did you add other assumptions elsewhere?

Comment: @MarcoB I see the same on 12.1 Mac OS. `ConditionalExpression[
 1/2 EllipticE[\[Pi] FractionalPart[(2 u)/\[Pi]], 100] + 
  EllipticE[100] IntegerPart[(2 u)/\[Pi]], 
 u \[Element] Reals && Cos[4 u] >= 49/50]`

Comment: If I change `Sqrt[...]` to `Surd[..., 2]` I get `Integrate::idiv: Integral of Surd[-49+50 Cos[4 t], 2] does not converge on {0,\[Pi]/2}.` and the result `ConditionalExpression[1/2 EllipticE[2 u, 100], 
 4 u < ArcCos[49/50] && 50 Cos[4 u] >= 49]`.

Comment: Note that the antiderivative `Integrate[Sqrt[1 - 100*Sin[2*t]^2], t]` gives the result you expect.  My best guess is that there's some kind of branch-cut checking that causes this, since the integrand has a singularity when $\sin (2t) = 1/10$ (or equivalently, $\cos(4t) = 49/50$.)

Comment: then, What should i do to avoid this branch-cut checking?Will the MMA support team help me to find this branch-cut checking?